# Cakephp: How to save `parent_id` into a Tree based Model deeply when using `saveAssociated()`?

Tags: cakephp, model, tree, save

My DB Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `alias` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `foreign_key` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `alias` (`alias`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `psos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `po_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lft` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rght` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

My Models Structure:

```
class Po extends Model {
    public $name = 'Po';
    public $useTable = 'pos';
    public $cacheQueries = false;
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Pso' => array(
            'className' => 'Pso',
            'foreignKey' => 'po_id',
            'dependent' => true,
        ),
        'Puso' => array(
            'className' => 'Puso',
            'foreignKey' => 'po_id',
            'dependent' => true,
        ),
    );
}

class Pso extends Model {
    public $name = 'Pso';
    public $useTable = 'psos';
    public $cacheQueries = false;
    public $actsAs = array(
        'Tree',
    );

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Parent' => array(
            'className' => 'Pso',
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
        ),
        'Po' => array(
            'className' => 'Po',
            'foreignKey' => 'po_id',
        ),
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Children' => array(
            'className' => 'Pso',
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
        ),
    );

}
```

My Saving Associated test code:

```
$Po->saveAssociated(array(
    'Po' => array(
        'alias' => 'teste'.uniqid(),
    ),
    'Pso' => array(
        'parent_id' => 2,
    ),
));
```

Resulting PSO saved Row:

```
array('id'=>4,'parent_id'=>0,'po_id'=>4,'lft'=>7,'rght'=>8)
```

Expected PSO saved Row:

```
array('id'=>4,'parent_id'=>2,'po_id'=>4,'lft'=>7,'rght'=>8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved like this:

```
$Po->saveAssociated(array(
    'Po' => array(
        'alias' => 'teste'.uniqid(),
    ),
    'Pso' => array(
        'parent_id' => array(
            'parent_id' => 2,
        ),
    ),
));
```